# Selecting Z-Up only faces

Tags: selection-tools, select

Does anyone know how to select all Z-Up only faces in this monstrocity please? I've selected a few as an example:

[image]

I've tried:

- Select Similar > Normal: that selects Z-Down as well. I've also tried calculating normals from faces and repeating the step with the same result.
- Select Similar > Linked flat faces: that seemed to select pretty randomly (I'm not surprised - this is entirely made of Ngons.
- Selecting all side faces with Select Similar, seperating them out and
  then from a top down view box trying to select them, hoping they would obscure the selection of the bottom faces in ortho view and I could add them layer by layer to a selection group then hide them but for some reason this often
  selects Z-Down too.
- Splitting the model at the edges and trying the above steps.

I'm guessing this would be simple in code if anyone has a snippet.

Comment: If _Select Similar_ > _Normal_ doesn't work you might need to add your file here. As @RobinBetts answered and I commented there, if your geometry is correct without any issues, the Z down faces should not be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> 'Recalculate Outside', maybe <kbd>M</kbd> merge by distance?  and checking for all-blue with Overlays > Face Orientation,  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> Select Similar > Normal should work fine.

Comment: I agree, if all faces are correctly oriented, none flipped, none maybe duplicated or anything, then _Select Similar_ > _Normal_ should not select faces that are Z down. Just tried it myself to be sure.

Comment: Hi @GordonBrinkmann! However simple a problem seems, I _never_ post an answer without trying it myself, immediately before posting, I've been burned too often :D

Comment: Yeah, this was more directed to the OP ;)

Comment: @RobinBetts Yup, Overlays > Face Orientation identified the problem. Looks like I've got some manual normal flipping to do, but still quicker than manually selecting all those faces (there are 3 other similar models to go!). On that note, is there any way to select all non-correct normals? They still exist after a recalc. Thanks.

Comment: @Absinthe .. IMO, depends on the failure of recalc, and whether you want to keep the characteristics that make it fail. Maybe share a representative  file on https://blend-exchange.com/.